# R bnlearn undirected arcs

Tags: r

I built a graph using bnlearn:hc using the following steps:

1. bootstrap 500 bns using hc algorithm
2. calculated the best threshold
3. extract the best arcs with threshold > "best threshold calculated" and direction > 0.5

So if I try to bootstrap with 1 bn, to be more fast in small tests, sometimes I have some undirected arcs.

In bnlearn how I can know what are the undirected arcs from a bn object (a learned structure) and remove it? This would be the best solution ?

Tks

Comment: You should not get undirected arcs if you are using a score based learning algorithm (such as `hc`). If you use a constraint basedalg you can randomly assign a direction using `cextend`

Comment: That said, I cant remember how bnlearn deals with the net if the threshold for an arc is exactly 0.5 (it may be retuned as undirected). If so, try running it for an odd number of bootstrap resamples.

Answer (score 1):

When there are many nodes it can be hard to pick out the undirected arcs in a graph.  In this case you can use undirected.arcs() to find them.

Usage is as follows:

```
boot = boot.strength(data = df, R=500, algorithm = 'hc', 
                     algorithm.args = list(score = 'bde'))
boot.avg = averaged.network(boot)
undirected.arcs(boot.avg)
```

You can check the scores of each arc direction to make sure one isn't greater than the other:

```
score(set.arc(boot.avg, from="A", to="B", df)
score(set.arc(boot.avg, from="B", to="A", df)
```

And then finally you will want to set a direction like so:

```
boot.avg = set.arc(boot.avg, from="A", to="B")
```

If you want to remove the arc entirely you can do so with:

```
boot.avg = drop.arc(boot.avg, from="A", to="B")
```

Answer (score 0):

To see which arcs are undirected you can plot the network.  Use `plot(network)` or, if you have the package `Rgraphviz`, you can use `graphviz.plot(network)`.